# What is the filtration in Leray's spectral sequence?

Tags: sheaf-theory, spectral-sequences, sheaf-cohomology

Leray's theory of spectral sequences considers a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces. The statement is that there exists a filtration 
$$H^n(X,k) = F^0H^n(X,k) \supseteq ... \supseteq F^nH^n(X,k),$$ $k$ being a ring, such that the subquotients of this filtration equals the terms $E_{\infty}^{p,n-p}$ of a spectral sequence which has $E_2$-term
$$E_2^{p,q} = H^p(Y,R^qf_* k),$$ where $R^qf_*k$ denotes the sheafification of the presheaf $U \to H^q(f^{-1}(U),k)$.

Where can I find a genuine construction of this filtration ? Is there a way to express it in terms of the skeletons of $Y$ (in the CW-complex case), as for the Serre spectral sequence ?
I would like to check that a certain homomorphism of cochain complexes induces a map between Leray spectral sequences, and thus I need to check that the map in question preserves this filtration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bott and Tu's book is quite explicit with the Leray spectral sequence for local systems on top. spaces.

Comment: Bott and Tu’s book defines a double complex based on the Cech complex and the complex of differential forms. In particular it supposes that the spaces are smooth manifolds, which I don’t want to assume.

Comment: Actually, they consider also fibrations over topological spaces and locally constant sheaves. See the next chapters. I don't have access to the book now, so I can't check the exact page.

Comment: I have checked again, and in any case they don’t treat the general case of continuous maps which are not fibration.

Comment: The general case works in the same way except that the second page won't be the cohomology of the constant sheaf $H^q (F, k)$. I may write the details later. Right now, I'm out of time.

Comment: Are you sure ? It seems that, in order to identify the $E_2$ page with the cohomology of the sheaf $R^q f_* k$, the fibration property is used extensively... 
Thanks a lot for your help, it would be amazing to get some details when you have time.

Comment: There is a way to construct a filtration which will give rise to a Leray spectral sequence (or more generally, Grothendieck spectral sequence for composed functors). For example, you can find the definition after equation (2) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0301140.pdf). However, I don't know whether it coincides with the filtration defined in Bott-Tu.